# Wonderground API. Key settings issue

Tags: android, weather

I'm usign Wondergroud APIs to get Weather infos for my Android apps.

I set Developer service in the Key Settings, but I don't know what happens when I will publish my applications, because the limit is set to 10 "Calls Per Minute".

My applications download this informations 1 time per minute but If I pubblish them I have to change my Key Settings?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Once per minute? you must have some fast-changing weather where you are.

I wouldn't publish an app containing your developer key.  There's a rate limit of 500 calls per day too, so a single person using your app would hit your limit in just over 8 hours.

You can [get a commercial license](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/pricing.html) for the wunderground apis, though your 1 call-per-minute rate will require one of the more expensive options.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Thi is really what I didn't understand. How I get a commercial use for the wunderground apis?

Comment: The link in my answer has some details on the available licenses, or contact them if you need more: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/pricing.html